# Google Docs Voice Typing Places a Microphone Icon that Doesn't Disappear until Chrome is Closed Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: google-chrome, microphone, drive, google

When using the Google Docs voice typing function a microphone appears in the top right corner:
[image: screenshot]

It gets replicated the more times you use it. The only way to make them disappear is to close Chrome.

Does anybody else have this problem? Can I `pkill` anything to make it disappear? The only option I have is to restart the Chrome browser.

Comment: @user68186 I don't think so. I just seems the microphone icon isn't released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue doesn't add any extra processing weight its something I just find personally annoying. Apart from logging out and into Ubuntu, the only way to remove the microphones appearing in the taskbar is restarting the `gnome-shell` by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and typing either "restart" or just "r".